# How to find smallest cluster of location which are within a given distance

Tags: python, geolocation, data-science

I have a set of co-ordinates in latitude and longitude format. I need to find the smallest cluster from these coordinates which are within say 50 mile distance to each other.

I am new to data science, how can I implement this in Python without using sklearn library.

Comment: What about K means?

Comment: Can't be used, since it is part of sklearn library

Comment: You can always DIY.

Comment: Is there an easy example of that? The ones I saw were two complicated to implement, for seemingly small problem and dataset I have

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/k-means-without-libraries-python-feb3572e2eef

Comment: thanks for the link, checked it...still too complex for a simplistic problem at hand. I implemented through numpy.histogram2d

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need to find distance and you're using XY coords, and you don't want to use extra libs, then maybe a place to start is to write a little funciton which finds the euclidean distance - you know a squared plus b squared equals c squared - Maybe something like this can get you started - this is a function which takes two tuples as coordinates, but it can also works for 3D coords if needed:

```
    import math
    def getEuclideanDistance(pointA, pointB):
        xA,yA = pointA
        # or for 3D coords, xA, yA, zA = pointA...
        xB,yB = pointB
        result = math.sqrt((xA-xB)**2 + (yA-yB)**2)  
        # or for distance in 3d:
        # result = math.sqrt((xA-xB)**2 + (yA-yB)**2 + (zA-zB)**2)  

        return (result)
```

We're using the **2 operator to bring the result to the 2nd power, and math.sqrt to do the rest.  I hope this puts you on the right track.

Comment: Hello Brent, I have the function which can calculate the distance between two cartesian coordinates. But how can I get the smallest cluster from those coordinates, without using k-means.

Comment: What is a cluster?

Comment: I am not sure, not a data science guy. Was hoping to get answers in this forum.